# Get TxId after send with metamask

Tags: web3js, transactions

I'm using web3 1.0 beta, and I'd like to get TxId before it's mine

I find a lot answer with `sendTransaction`, but If I use it I get `sendTransaction is not a function`

My code is like this:

```
c.istanza.methods.registraTicket(matricola).send({
   from: c.defaultAccount
}).then(
(valore) => {....},
(err) => {....})
```

In this way, from my client, I can call my function in my Smart contract.
c.istanza is `istanza = new web3.eth.Contract(data.abi, data.address);`

If i Use something like this

```
c.istanza.methods.registraTicket(matricola).sendTransaction({
            from: c.defaultAccount
        }).then(
            (valore) => {

            },
            (err) => {
                console.dir(err);
            }
        )
```

I have a problem `sendTransaction is not a function`.

How can I get TxId before it mined?
I want to have this id, because I store it in Database and I can check when it's mined (it's correct to check this ?)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `send` is here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send.

It looks like you want the `transactionHash` event of the return value. The example from the documentation is as follows:

```
// using the event emitter
myContract.methods.myMethod(123).send({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'})
.on('transactionHash', function(hash){
    ...
})
```

("Transaction hash" is I assume what you mean by "TxId".)